# Why is Laravel adding fragment '#/' at the end of my URLs?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Why is Laravel adding fragment '#/' at the end of my URLs ?

For instance, when I open these URLs:

```
http://home.test/login
http://home.test/register
```

I get this result:

```
http://home.test/login#/
http://home.test/register#/
```

Comment: What frontend framework are you using? Are you getting the `#` when you click on a button to those URLs or when you type the URLs directly into your browser?

Comment: Laravel is not adding a fragment. Are you using a frontend framework by chance? Vue or Angular?

Comment: I'm using Vue, and yes, I get it even if I type the URL directly into my browser.

Comment: Add the vue tag to the question. Are you using vue router?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `vue-router`.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Vue then you now in mode `hash`. If you want to remove that fragment then you change to `history` mode.